# Data not returning using Parse Backend

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-recyclerview

Here i am trying to get the name of all the files stored on the backend server using Parse.com When I debug by specifying debug point then the data is showing in my app. But when i try run normally then the data is not displayed in the app. I have used RecyclerView to display the data(name of files). Below is the code to get the file name.

```
public List<FileModel> getAllFiles() {
    final List<FileModel> fileModelData = new ArrayList<>();

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Documents");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            String onlyFileName;
            String newFileName;
            for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
                ParseFile file = (ParseFile) objects.get(i).get("DocumentFile");
                Log.e("Object " + i, "" + file.getName() + "\n");

                onlyFileName = file.getName();
                Toast.makeText(context, "File " + i + " " + onlyFileName.substring(onlyFileName.lastIndexOf('-') + 1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Only File Name", onlyFileName.substring(onlyFileName.lastIndexOf('-') + 1));
                newFileName = onlyFileName.substring(onlyFileName.lastIndexOf('-') + 1);
                //onlyFileName = onlyFileName.substring(onlyFileName.lastIndexOf('-')+1);
                fileModelData.add(new FileModel(newFileName));
                Log.e("fileModelData ", "" + fileModelData.size());
            }

        }
    });
   /* Log.e("fileModelData " , ""+fileModelData.size());*/
    return fileModelData;
}
```

This is the code for RecyclerView.

```
GetFiles getFiles = new GetFiles(SearchFilesActivity.this);
    List<FileModel> data = getFiles.getAllFiles();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
    adapter = new FileNameAdapter(this,data);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I don't know where I am missing something. Please help me. The data what we are getting is done by using done() method of ParseQuery Class which is handled in background.

Answer (score 0):

Since findInBackground() is asynchronous call, hence getAllFiles() method may return before the done callback. This is the reason data is not populated in the list.
Try using find() method or inform adapter via setting callback(use interface to update adapter).